# Stop indenting the second line in list

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, enumitem

I want to be able to stop indenting the second line in the list and still keep the indentation of the first line. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[multi={minipage}, border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{500bp}
\fontsize{20}{24}
\selectfont
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex,leftmargin=3ex]
\item{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.}
\item{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

For example, in the following I want to remove the indentation before the underlined term:

[image: Want to remove indentation before the underlined term]

Comment: What is the `minipage` meant for?

Comment: Just for a better appearance of the minimal working example. @ChristianHupfer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shows no indentation at all after the first line of each item, perhaps you want to indent to the label position?

[image]

```
\documentclass[multi={minipage}, border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{500bp}
\fontsize{20}{24}
\selectfont
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex,leftmargin=0pt,
itemindent=3em]
\item{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.}
\item{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So the key was itemindent=3ex and leftmargin=0pt.

Comment: @user292139 yes itemindent is the indent at the start (although visual effect affected by labelwidth and labelsep as well) leftmargin is the indent for the whole idem

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[multi={minipage}, border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{500bp}
\begin{enumerate}[
    topsep=0pt,
    itemsep=-1ex,
    partopsep=1ex,
    parsep=1ex,
    leftmargin=0ex,
    itemindent=3ex
    ]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

The simplest is to use the `wide=` option. Here are two variants:

```
\documentclass[multi={minipage}, border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{500bp}
  \fontsize{20}{24}
  \selectfont
  \begin{enumerate}[wide =1em]
    \item{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.}
    \item{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{500bp}
  \fontsize{20}{24}
  \selectfont
  \begin{enumerate}[wide]
    \item{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.}
    \item{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]